# Modal only appearing after double click

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have implemented bootstrap modals in the following way

```
  Template.dashboardLayout.events({
  'click .showModal': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var name = template.$(event.target).data('modal-template');
    Session.set('activeModal', name);
    $('.modal').modal();
  },

  /* Hide modal on ESC
   */
  'keyup': function(event, template) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      $('.modal').modal('hide');
    }
  }
});

Template.modal.helpers({
  activeModal: function() {
    return Session.get('activeModal');
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<button id="showNewTabForm" data-modal-template="newTab"
    class="btn btn-default btn-primary showModal pull-left">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Tab
</button>
```

And then in my main layout

```
<template name="dashboardLayout">

  <div class="background-image"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    {{> header}}

    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        {{> sidebar}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        {{> content}}
        {{> footer}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{> modal}}
</template>
```

However, whenever I click the .openModel button the first time, it doesn't show, although the event fires, but on the second click, it opens correctly

Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: Syntax error around `button id` ?

Comment: copy/paste error, my bad

Comment: it would be easier to find help if you wrapped things in a fiddle or snipped replicating the issue.

Comment: Try using `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`. `event.target` refers to the element you clicked on, which could be `<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>`, while `event.currentTarget` refers to the element your event selector (in your case `.showModal`, the button) refers to. BTW, I've created a [package for showing bootstrap 3 modals](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal) in Meteor, feel free to use it.